# poor pyspark query performance

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to migrate from a single node pure python/pandas workflow to a parallel workflow using spark cluster because i'm running into performance and OOM issues as the dataset is getting larger and larger. As a PoC, i've been trying to convert one part of my code which I think is best case for spark because the entire thing is pandas aggregates and very little of python just for collecting the data and writing to a db at the end.

This is what the code currently does: aggregates values for each userid for each month, in pseudo code:

```
dates_to_process = [LIST OF DATES(FIRST OF MONTH. eg: 1/1/2010:00:00:00.0000) GOING BACK SEVERAL YEARS]
for uid, df in datafame.groupby('userid'):
      for start_date in dates_to_process:
          end_date = last_of_month(start_date) // this will be 31/1/2010:23:59:59.9999)
          current_month = df[df['date'] >= start_date & df['date'] <= end_date]
          // here run a bunch of queries like
          val1 = df[col1].sum()
          val2 = df[(col2) == "somestring"][col3].sum()
          val3 = df.groupby(col4).mean(col5)
          val4 = df[df[col6] <= end_date][col7].value_counts()
          // and so on. maybe 200 - 250 such calculations
          // collect the values and put it in new dataframe which gets written to db at the end
```

I tried doing it in pyspark, but it turned out I need to call `count()` and `collect()` way too often and probably more often than recommended. And it takes maybe 3 minutes per userid (about 1500 unique userids) in a 3 million row dataframe.

Is there a better way of doing this or is spark not the right tool for this kind of job? I tried running on a local cluster of 2 other machines and the performance didn't improve all that much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet , you should look at [Pandas UDF](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html), which would also allow you to reuse your existing native pandas code snippets as well.

Introducing a loop like that does not provide much gains in Spark , stick to native functions which are optimised

A typical example of Pandas UDF is as below -

Here I m trying to find out similar names utilising `applyInPandas` as an example

Primarily you need to supply the output `schema` after your custom pandas function returns

#### Data Preparation

```
df1 = sql.createDataFrame([
 ["Luc Krier"],
 ["Jeanny Thorn"],
 [ "Teddy E Beecher"],
 ["Philippe Schauss"],
 ["Meindert I Tholen"],
 ["John I Muller"]
]).toDF("name")

df2 = sql.createDataFrame([
 ["J. Thorn"],
 ["Ben Weller"],
 [ "L. Krier"],
 ["J.M. Thorn"],
 ["Liam Muller"],
 ["Meindert Tholen"]
]).toDF("name")


df1 = df1.withColumn('id',F.lit(1))
df2 = df2.withColumn('id',F.lit(1))

combined_df = df1.join(df2
                      ,df1['id'] == df2['id']
                      ).select(df1['name'],df2['name'].alias('name_proxy'))


combined_df.filter(F.col('name') == 'Luc Krier').show()

+---------+---------------+
|     name|     name_proxy|
+---------+---------------+
|Luc Krier|       J. Thorn|
|Luc Krier|     Ben Weller|
|Luc Krier|       L. Krier|
|Luc Krier|     J.M. Thorn|
|Luc Krier|    Liam Muller|
|Luc Krier|Meindert Tholen|
+---------+---------------+
```

#### Pandas UDF

```
schema = StructType([
           StructField('name', StringType(), True),
           StructField('name_proxy', StringType(), True),
           StructField('match', BooleanType(), True)
 ])

def whos_who_match(inp_df,match_columns):
    
    inp_df['match'] = inp_df[match_columns].apply(lambda x : who.match(x[0],x[1]),axis=1)
    
    return inp_df

partial_func = partial(whos_who_match,match_columns=['name','name_proxy'])

combined_df = combined_df.groupby('name').applyInPandas(partial_func,schema)

combined_df.filter(F.col('match') == True).show()

+-----------------+---------------+-----+
|             name|     name_proxy|match|
+-----------------+---------------+-----+
|Meindert I Tholen|Meindert Tholen| true|
|     Jeanny Thorn|       J. Thorn| true|
|        Luc Krier|       L. Krier| true|
+-----------------+---------------+-----+
```